# custom dialog using android-support-v7appcompat

Tags: android, dialog, title

I add the library android-support-v7 appcompat on my project and now my customized dialog doesn't show the title. Why?

My file `styles.xml`:

```
 <style name="cust_dialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/dialog_title_style</item>
    </style>

    <style name="dialog_title_style" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:background">@color/orange_logo</item>
        <item name="android:height">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/TextSize_title_dialog</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
public void customDialog() {
        Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_submit);
        dialog.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

res/layout/title.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="title comes here"/>
```